# Given the CBC-MAC for a message M and the key K, How could I forge a new message M' so that it has the same CBC-Mac as M

Tags: cbc-mac, forgery

Im looking to learn about forging CBC-Macs.

Given the CBC-Mac for a Message M and the Key used to encrypt the message K.

Can I create a new message M' which would have the same CBC-MAC?

Original Unknown Message: M

CBC-Mac of Original Unknown Message: X

Key used in CBC Block cipher: K

New message with CBC-Mac = X: M'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insecurity of CBC-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35454/insecurity-of-cbc-mac)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a new message M' which would have the same CBC-MAC?

Sure can.

On the other hand, you're *learning*, and I believe you learn better by figuring out it yourself, and so I'll just give a hint.

Suppose you selected an arbitrary string $A$ (which is a multiple of the block size in length), and an arbitrary string $B$; how could you find string $X$ (which is one block size in length) such that $CBC-MAC_k(A || X || B ) = Target$?

Hint: with CBC mode, you can compute things in the reverse direction - if you know the state after $i$ blocks, and you know the key and the previous message block, you can compute the state after $i-1$ blocks...

Comment: Hey Poncho, Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly Im still a bit puzzled. So far I have figured out that I can get Cipher Text N - 2 XORed with Plain text N-1 by decrypting the MAC. Can you help me any further

Comment: @TomScott: so, how can you get ciphertext $N-2$ for a message that you selected?